# Cisco Switch: Trying to dump mac address info from switch to server

Tags: mac-osx, networking, cisco

The command: show mac address-table gives me me mac address info i like. I'm trying to figure out to get this to dump to a server once a month as a text file. Each time it would dump, the previous file would be overwritten with the new one. 
Lets say the switch is 192.168.4.6 and computer is 192.168.4.7
Do I need to setup TFTP or SNMP?
Could this even be done?

Answer (score 1):

You could use Kiwi cat tools to schedule running the command and log the output to a file

Answer (score 0):

Check if your switch supports the redirect command

Show mac address-table | redirect tftp://192.168.4.7/switch-macs.txt

If that is supported you could write a kron to do it monthly ( assuming the switch supports kron )

The kron syntax here might not be exact

Kron policy 1 
 Cli Show mac address-table | redirect tftp://192.168.4.7/switch-macs.txt

Kron schedule 1 in 24 recurring